# What is a distributed force?

Tags: terminology, elasticity

I was reading a book called "Properties of Matter" by D.S. Mathur. And In the chapter titled "Elasticity", The book said that "Stress" is measured per unit area due to it being a distributed force. What does that mean? I also had trouble understanding why Stress is measured as force per unit area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does that (a distributed force) mean? I also had trouble
>   understanding why Stress is measured as force per unit area.

Think about stress in the same way as pressure. In mechanics of materials, stress or pressure expresses the internal forces between neighboring particles (atoms, molecules, etc.) of materials. The units of stress are the same as pressure.

The diagram below shows a vertically oriented cylinder of cross section area $A$ with a disc of mass $m$ placed on top. The downward force of the disc is $mg$. The axial or normal stress on the cross section area of the cylinder is the result of the disc force being distributed uniformly over the cross section area and equals $F/A=mg/A$.

For any given cross section area within the cylinder material, the stress will be the sum of the weight of the disc plus the weight of cylinder above the cross section, divided by cross sectional area.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: The explanation was really thorough. The diagram helped a lot. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's a force distributed over an area, and that's how it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

Force is widely used to study the behaviour of particles. Stress is a useful definition to design mechanical or structural elements.

For example: A roll of a rolling mill has a central part with a larger diameter (barrel) and 2 sides with smaller diameter (necks). It is loaded by the bar in the barrel, and supported at both necks by the bearings.

In a case of overload, it may break in the region of sudden increase of diameter, between neck and barrel, where there is no applied force, but where stress is high.

Answer (score 0):

A distributed force is as opposed to a point force. While there is no perfect point force,  idealised point forces are used when calculating statics or dynamics of whole bodies or systems. Distributed forces are more helpful when we need to know, for example, if a material will fail in a particular location. This can be done by determining the distribution of all relevant forces in the surrounding region, and then allocating the aggregate effect on that location.